# How to solve Angular data service function error?

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I want to get data from my firebase real time db with the following function:

```
  getTasks() {
    if ( this.orgId === this.db.list(`users/${this.uId}/organization`) ) {
      this.db.list(`users/${this.uId}/product_views`);
    } else
    return;
  }
```

But VS Code shows me this error:
*This condition will always return 'false' since the types 'string' and 'AngularFireList' have no overlap.ts(2367)*

Unfortunately I am completely new to JS or TS and have no idea how to fix it.

Comment: Try to use `==` and check also types of both vars

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. How to check the type of: this.db.list(`users/${this.uId}/organization`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typecast your if condition:

```
getTasks() {
  if ( String(this.orgId) === String(this.db.list(`users/${this.uId}/organization`)) ) {
    this.db.list(`users/${this.uId}/product_views`);
  } else
  return;
}
```

or change '===' with '==';

```
getTasks() {
  if ( this.orgId == this.db.list(`users/${this.uId}/organization`) ) {
    this.db.list(`users/${this.uId}/product_views`);
  } else
  return;
}
```